# how to interpret no change in chi square value in measurement invariance analysis, using lavaan

Tags: measurement, lavaan, invariance

Currently I am using `lavaan` R package to do some measurement invariance analyses. One warning that I get confuses me a little bit:

```
Warning message:
In lavTestLRT(object = new("lavaan", version = "0.6.7", call = lavaan::lavaan(model = cfa_model,  :
  lavaan WARNING: some restricted models fit better than less 
     restricted models; either these models are not nested, or
     the less restricted model failed to reach a global optimum.
```

The steps I take in making parameters equal are: 1. all paramaters are free, 2. loadings are equal in all groups, 3. loadings and intercepts are equal in all groups, 4. loadings, intercepts and residuals are equal in all groups.

The outcome of the analysis is:

[image]

As you can see, the chi sqare values of model 2 and model 3 are the same. That's where the error comes from obviously.
My conclusion is thate the consequeing models are perfectly netsted. So there seems something wrong with the optimization. Does anyone know what could be the problem here and, hopefully, how to fix it?